# How do I use .babelrc to get babel-plugin-import working for antd?

Tags: babeljs, create-react-app, antd

I'm new to react, babel, and antd.

I installed react and started a project using create-react-app.
I installed antd (ant.design).  It suggests using babel-plugin-import, so I installed that too.

If I interpret it right, the usage documentation for babel-plugin-import says to put this in a .babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["import", {
      "libraryName": "antd",
      "style": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

I'm having trouble getting it to work.  My web console still has the warning:

> You are using a whole package of antd, please use
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import to reduce app bundle
>   size.

I didn't have a .babelrc file in my project's directory, so I created one with the above contents and restarted my server (npm start).  That didn't work, so I created one in myProject/node_modules/babel_plugin_import but that doesn't work either.

Where is that code snippet supposed to go?

At the bottom of https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import it says

> babel-plugin-import will be not working if you add the library in
>   webpack config vender.

But I don't know what that means.

I asked another question here: [How to get antd working with app created via create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035080/how-to-get-antd-working-with-app-created-via-create-react-app)
Maybe this problem has something to do with my project created via create-react-app??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Update 2018-02-06**: The answer is still correct, but there is a better alternative now, which is to use `react-app-rewired`. This is also documented in the link.]

You need to follow the instructions in https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Import-on-demand to a T.

You should **not** create ant `.babelrc` files or similar. When using CRA all babel config is handled inside the webpack config files.

First clean up the config files you created, and make sure you have `babel-plugin-import` installed.

Then eject your app: `npm run eject`

This will give you a `config` folder with 2 webpack config files for dev/prod environments.

Open those files and locate the place where you need to insert the `plugins` property as documented on the instructions page.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I didn't know about the "Use in create-react-app" section, I was still stuck at "Getting Started".

Comment: With the upgrade to CRA 2.0, this is again an issue! :(

Answer (score 1):

Just add what **babel-plugin-import** documentation says, but remember if you're using CRA, you cannot change babel configuration directly without ejecting the project.

If you don't want to eject, you can use **@craco/craco**, and put the babel configuration inside of it like this:

```
/* craco.config.js */

module.exports = {
  babel: {
    presets: [],
    plugins: [
      [
        "import",
        {
          libraryName: "antd",
          style: true, // or 'css'
        },
      ],
    ],
    loaderOptions: {
      /* Any babel-loader configuration options: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader. */
    },
  },
};
```

Dont forget to change your scripts (more details in craco docs):

```
/* package.json */

"scripts": {
-   "start": "react-scripts start",
+   "start": "craco start",
-   "build": "react-scripts build",
+   "build": "craco build"
-   "test": "react-scripts test",
+   "test": "craco test"
}
```