# Customizing antd Less or Css for create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, redux, less, create-react-app, antd

I am using create-react-app as starter kit and was having a go at `antd` component library.

I can't seem to find a way to customize their styles (for branding purpose). Documentation doesn't seem to give clear directions regarding customization.

Docs link: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

They suggest two ways to do it though :

1.Using `theme` property . But this only works for `antd-init` or `dva-cli` boilerplates and not for `create-react-app`

2.Overriding `Less` variables .

Now to make the either of these option work for `create-react-app` without `eject` , what are the steps I need to take?

Answer (score 1):

You question is not very well researched I am afraid. At a minimum, read the obvious resurces like the instructions at https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app and older Stackoverflow questions (like [How do I use .babelrc to get babel-plugin-import working for antd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034773/)) before posting a question.

As it stands, CRA does not support changing the Babel configuration. This is needed to include the antd babel-plugin, which is needed to support importing only the necessary antd modules.

As a result you can only import the whole monolithic antd in a non-ejected CRA app.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't too clear with my question, may be I should have asked like : how to make the either of these option work for `create-react-app ` without `eject`. I have updated the question now. I read the documentation and all the steps they have mentioned suggest to `eject` . My preference would be to find out a way to theme it without the `eject` option as I have will have flexibility to update `react-scripts` later on.

Comment: Currently you cannot run _modular_ antd in CRA without eject, as it requires a babel plugin, and CRA does not allow babel plugins without ejecting.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper We . But could you explain more on when you say _modular_ antd? Also, I though of another way to make this work by copying the antd.css in src , importing in index.js and importing another custom.css file which overrides the styles which I want to override  . What do you think about this approach?

Comment: "Modular" means that webpack includes only the Antd modules you actually use, not the whole package. With a non-ejected CRA app, it always imports the whole bundle. It is a bit large. This may or may not be an issue for you depending on how your app is used.

Comment: See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/670 for the discussion of adding plugins to CRA.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't intend to use eject you should use config-overrides.js to specify how you want to modify the default webpack.config.js that is part of react-scripts.  Then once you have a config-overrides you can add a less Rule that has an option for modifyVars.  Here you can specify any changes to the less variables.

```
function addLessRule(config, env)
{
  const { getLoader, loaderNameMatches } = require("react-app-rewired");

  const fileLoader = getLoader(
    config.module.rules,
    rule => loaderNameMatches(rule, 'file-loader')
  );

  const lessExtension = /\.less$/;
  fileLoader.exclude.push(lessExtension);

  const cssRules = getLoader(
    config.module.rules,
    rule => String(rule.test) === String(/\.css$/)
  );

  var lessModifyVars = {
    'primary-color': '#990000',
    'link-color': '#1DA57A',
    'border-radius-base': '2px',
    'layout-header-background' : '#f0f2f5'
  };

  var lessLoaders = [
    { loader: 'style-loader'} ,
    { loader: 'css-loader' },
    { loader: 'less-loader', options: {
      modifyVars: lessModifyVars
    } }
   ];

  lessRule = {
    test : lessExtension,
    use: lessLoaders,
  }

  config.module["rules"].push( lessRule );
  return config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize antd without using `react eject` and don't want to change use forked versions of `create-react-app` or `react scripts` then

you can simply create a less file (let's say main.less ) , import antd.less and replace the default variables of ant design in this main.less file.

Now compile this less file using lessc (`npm i -g less`).

```
lessc "main.less antd.css" --js
```

--js is for inline javascript in less
Now simply include these complied css in your app.

take a look at https://medium.com/@aksteps/782c53cbc03b